# How can I vectorise this python code or make it efficient? Transforming an array using a mapping

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, optimization

I have a 2-D Numpy array `A (id1 x time)` and want to **construct** another array `B (id2 x time)` using a mapping from id2 to id1 (or vice versa). The mapping of id2 to id1 differs along time and is stored in a dictionary, `{t: {id2:id1}}`, which maps from an element of A to an element of B.

For eg. (I have considered id's to be same as indexes in this example):

```
A = np.arange(20).reshape((5,4))
B = np.full((3,4), np.nan)

A = np.array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3],
              [ 4,  5,  6,  7],
              [ 8,  9, 10, 11],
              [12, 13, 14, 15],
              [16, 17, 18, 19]])
B = np.array([[np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan],
              [np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan],
              [np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan]])
id_dict = {0: {0: '0', 1: '2', 2: '3'},
             1: {0: '1', 2: '3'},
             2: {0: '1', 1: '2', 2: '3'},
             3: {0: '2', 1: '2', 2: '4'}}
```

Below is my implementation of the solution:

```
b_idx = np.arange(B.shape[0])
for t in range(A.shape[1]):
    id_dict_t = id_dict[t]                        ## Get dict for each column
    a_idx = np.vectorize(id_dict_t.get(b_idx))    
    none_mask = a_idx != 'None'                   ## Handle case where nomapping exists
    B[b_idx[none_mask],t] = A[a_idx[none_mask].astype('int'),t]

B = array([[ 0.,  5.,  6., 11.],
           [ 8., nan, 10., 11.],
           [12., 13., 14., 19.]])
```

Can I do this more efficiently?

**Extra Comments:**

1. The id1 to id2 mapping is a one-to-many mapping on the time axis. As in the example above, there can be missing id2 to id1 values in which case we should get `np.nan`. This can be stored in a matrix of size B as well...
2. `#time points >> #id1 > #id2`. Maybe preprocessing the `id_dict` to loop over id1/id2 could be a better way but I cannot figure out how I could achieve that.
3. I converted id1 to string in the `id_dict` since `np.vectorise` gives an issue otherwise (Nonetype cannot be int). However, that is not relevant to the question persay.

Thanks! Kindly comment if something needs more explanation or if there is some editing issue since this is my first time posting a question here.

Edit: Made the example more accurate. Also, if required, the mapping at each time is actually unique (one-to-one). May be helpful in memory reduction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way would be to convert the mapping dictionary to an array of indices:

```
mapping = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(id_dict, orient='columns').astype(float).values
mapped = np.diagonal(A[np.where(np.isnan(mapping), 0, mapping).astype(int)], axis1=1, axis2=2)
B = np.where(np.isnan(mapping), np.nan, mapped)
```

Note that unavailable mappings are replaced first with a dummy value and then replaced with `np.nan` in the last line.

Comment: Oh, this is pretty genius! I could not wrap my head around 2-D indexing while trying to take the issue. Unfortunately, the 2-D indexed matrix is  `(#id2 x #time x #time)` which makes the memory blowup. Could there be any other way to tackle this?

Comment: * 3-D indexed matrix - `A[np.where(np.isnan(mapping), 0, mapping).astype(int)]`

Comment: @KaustubhPrakash Is `np.vstack([A[:, i][np.where(np.isnan(mapping), 0, mapping).astype(int)[:, i]] for i in range(A.shape[-1])]).T` too slow?

Comment: For the small example, it ran pretty quickly (using %timeit), but for my data, it did not even run completely. Using tqdm estimated about 30 mins of runtime, while the for loop method works in about 1 minute. Maybe vectorising is not a good solution due to memory constraints. Anyways, appreciate the effort, I have accepted the answer for now in case someone wants to vectorise a similar example. Thanks a lot!